# SQLite Memory Database Won't Close

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying my first in-memory database using SQLite. I read that after the last connection closes, the database will be destroyed.

In my code I accidentally didn't close a connection the first time I ran it and now every time I open the application the database already exists and the tables inside already exist as well.

Here is the connection string I used:

```
connectionString = "Data Source=InMemorySample;Mode=Memory;Cache=Shared";
```

Here is how I'm checking if the table already exists as soon as I start my application:

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'
```

This returns the table names of the tables I created last time I opened the application.

My question is - how do I get this phantom connection to close so this in-memory database will be deleted? I've even tried restarting my computer and it is still there!

Thanks,
John

Comment: You're not using a memory-only database; you have a database file sitting around somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Shawn. You're right. I found the files. I'm using Mono, I've tried both these connection parameters now too. URI and Data Source versions:

Comment: URI=file::memory:?cache=shared;Version=3. Do you know how I can create a shared in-memory database using Mono?

Comment: I have no clue about mono or its sqlite bindings.